# How do I use the result from FB FQL multiquery?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, fql.multiquery

I'm confused by Facebook's fql.multiquery method.

I'm trying to retrieve all the comments on a post, and then the user information for each one as well.  I can get the comments without any problem, but I'm having trouble getting the users.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
  FB.api({
   method: 'fql.multiquery',
   queries: {
    query1: 'SELECT post_fbid, fromid, text, time FROM comment WHERE post_id="'+postID +'"',
    query2: 'SELECT id, name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)'
   }
  },
  function(response) {
  }
})
```

This gives me the following response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "query1",
    "fql_result_set": [
      {
        "post_fbid": "xxxxx",
        "fromid": user1id,
        "text": "Here's a comment",
        "time": 1308579931
      },
      {
        "post_fbid": "xxxxx",
        "fromid": user2id,
        "text": "Another comment",
        "time": 1308580031
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "query2",
    "fql_result_set": [
      {
        "id": user1id,
        "name": "User 1 name",
        "url": "User 1 url",
        "pic": "User 1 pic"
      },
      {
        "id": user2id,
        "name": "User 2 name",
        "url": "User 2 url",
        "pic": "User 2 pic"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Problem is, I don't know how to match these up!  So I'm looping over the comments, and want to print the text of each one with the user's name next to it.  How do I do that?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could match these results up by looping over the comments and matching the fromid to an id from the users response.

For example:

```
    var comments = response[0].fql_result_set;
    var users = response[1].fql_result_set;    

    //loop through the comments
    for(var i = 0, j = comments.length; i<j; i++){

        for(var x = 0, y = users.length; x<y; x++){
             if(comments[i].fromid == users[x].id){
                 //we have a match, this comment is from user users[x]
                 //process users[x]
                 //break the inner for loop, since we already have a match
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!  You've really helped me out - thanks again.

Comment: No problem. The old REST API can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: I can't believe this kind of stuff is so glossed over in Facebook's documentation. Thank you!

Comment: This is a method I use, but I would like to discover a better method that improves the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with PHP and need a single array of comments to loop through this function might come in handy:

```
public function getComments($objectID){
    $user = $comment =array();
    $q1 = "/fql?q=".urlencode("SELECT  id, fromid, text, time , likes FROM comment WHERE object_id ='$objectID' ");
    $res = $this->api($q1);
    $com = $res['data'];

    $q2 = "/fql?q=".urlencode("SELECT uid, name, username, pic_small, current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id ='$objectID' )");
    $res = $this->api($q2);
    $usr = $res['data']; 

    foreach($usr as $k=>$v){
        $user[$v['uid']] = $v;
    }
    foreach($com as $cmnt){
        $comment[$cmnt['id']] = $cmnt;
        $comment[$cmnt['id']]['user'] = $user[$cmnt['fromid']];
    }
     return $comment;
}
```

Returns a single array of comments with the commentID as key:

```
Array(

[137194739772009_249649] => Array
    (
        [id] => 137194739772009_249649
        [fromid] => 1454592211
        [text] => Brilliant!
        [time] => 1357450854
        [likes] => 1
        [user] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 1454592211
                [name] => Jo Payne
                [username] => jo.payne.127
                [pic_small] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/203035_1454592211_505092710_t.jpg
                [current_location] => Array
                    (
                        [city] => Pascoe Vale
                        [state] => Victoria
                        [country] => Australia
                        [zip] => 
                        [id] => 107340732634422
                        [name] => Pascoe Vale, Victoria, Australia
                    )

            )

    )

[137194739772009_252711] => Array
    (
        [id] => 137194739772009_252711
        [fromid] => 1734247348
        [text] => testing
        [time] => 1357531321
        [likes] => 0
        [user] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 1734247348
                [name] => Andreas Lustig
                [username] => andreaslustigcom
                [pic_small] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/275058_1734247348_2025403101_t.jpg
                [current_location] => Array
                    (
                        [city] => Melbourne
                        [state] => Victoria
                        [country] => Australia
                        [zip] => 
                        [id] => 116190411724975
                        [name] => Melbourne, Victoria, Australia
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Note: you must pass a *numeric* objectID for this to work 100%. If you're object is a website the URL *might* work, but not always as I found out. Better to get a numeric ObjectID via the Object Debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q={YOUR URL HERE}

This is the only *reliable* way I found to get a numeric Object ID. The ObjectID will be on the last line:
Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR OBJECT ID}