# one fql to get photo with owner name

Tags: facebook-fql

I am writing a fql as below.

```
fql='SELECT caption, owner, pid, src_big, created FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (11111) ) LIMIT 1,5';
```

The problem is: how to write one fql to get the owner name also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may get owner name by joining the two tables photo and album. I am not sure how your table columns are but i suppose you must have an pid in album table so you can link tables likes this.

```
SELECT caption, owner, pid, src_big, created FROM photo LEFT JOIN album ON photo.pid=album.pid where aid IN (11111) LIMIT 1,5
```

Comment: But i understand that fql does not allow table joining. I have also tried it in the fql console and the following result is got. "Parser error: unexpected 'LEFT' at position 56".

Comment: Upsss  sorry for that. :(                                           This link might help you it shows you how to use fql_multiquery() [link](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/must-use-fql-multiquery-to-retrieve-data/)

Comment: There was a question asked the other day that involves using FQL multiquery. I think it may help you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459292/how-do-i-use-the-result-from-fb-fql-multiquery