# Facebook C# SDKv6 How to Parse results of Multi Query FQL

Tags: json, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I can successfully execute a multi query fql using the facebook c# sdk v 6.14 thanks to [Prabir's](http://blog.prabir.me/category/Facebook-C-SDK.aspx) blog, but need help in parsing the results. I've searched and tried many ways to no avail. I know it is a simple syntax issue, but I'm fairly new to c# and JSON.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Chad

My Code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(this.FacebookAccessToken);
            dynamic resultsMQFQL = fb.Get("fql",
                            new
                            {
                                q = new
                                {
                                    friendsMovies = "SELECT page_id, uid FROM page_fan WHERE type='MOVIE' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY page_id",
                                    movieDetails = "SELECT page_id, name, pic, fan_count, categories, genre, starring, release_date FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #friendsMovies) ORDER BY fan_count DESC",
                                }
                            });
```

Results:

```
{"data":[
    {"name":"friendsMovies",
        "fql_result_set":
            [{"page_id":105638652803531,"uid":796419451},
            {"page_id":113271808686307,"uid":796419451}]},

    {"name":"movieDetails",
        "fql_result_set":[
            {"page_id":105638652803531,"name":"Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas"},
            {"page_id":113271808686307,"name":"Fletch"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Attempt at parsing:

```
foreach (dynamic row in resultsMQFQL.data.fql_result_set)
```

Error:

```
'Facebook.JsonArray' does not contain a definition for 'fql_result_set'
```

Comment: Oh, and I tried this var comments = response[0].fql_result_set;
    var users = response[1].fql_result_set; [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459292/how-do-i-use-the-result-from-fb-fql-multiquery/6459569#6459569), and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out...forgot I could try various combinations quickly while debugging in the immediate window...did I say I am fairly new at coding? :)

```
public void FBMQFQL()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(this.FacebookAccessToken);
            dynamic resultsMQFQL = fb.Get("fql",
                            new
                            {
                                q = new
                                {
                                    friendsMovies = "SELECT page_id, uid FROM page_fan WHERE type='MOVIE' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY page_id",
                                    movieDetails = "SELECT page_id, name, pic, fan_count, categories, genre, starring, release_date FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #friendsMovies) ORDER BY fan_count DESC",
                                }
                            });

            //To access a direct value: resultsMQFQL.data[0].fql_result_set[0].page_id

            var friendsMovies = resultsMQFQL.data[0].fql_result_set;
            var movieDetails = resultsMQFQL.data[1].fql_result_set;

            if (resultsMQFQL == null)
            {
                //return null;
            }
            else
            {
                //Construct the new, formated, merged datatable to store the results the way we want them   
                DataTable dtMyFriendsMovies = new DataTable();
                dtMyFriendsMovies.Columns.Add("MovieID");
                dtMyFriendsMovies.Columns.Add("FriendUserID");

                foreach (dynamic row in friendsMovies)
                {
                    //Add New DataRow to new DataTable
                    DataRow drRow = dtMyFriendsMovies.NewRow();

                    //Get various values from original JSON Friend List returned
                    drRow["MovieID"] = row.page_id;
                    drRow["FriendUserID"] = row.uid;

                    //Add New Row to New Resulting Data Table
                    dtMyFriendsMovies.Rows.Add(drRow);
                }

                //MovieDetails   
                DataTable dtMovies = new DataTable();

                dtMovies.Columns.Add("movieID");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("name");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("pic");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("fan_count");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("genre");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("starring");
                dtMovies.Columns.Add("release_date");

                foreach (dynamic row in movieDetails)
                {
                    //Add New DataRow to new DataTable
                    DataRow drRow = dtMovies.NewRow();

                    //Get various values from original JSON Friend List returned
                    drRow["movieID"] = row.page_id;
                    drRow["name"] = row.name;
                    drRow["pic"] = row.pic;
                    drRow["fan_count"] = row.fan_count;
                    drRow["genre"] = row.genre;
                    drRow["starring"] = row.starring;
                    drRow["release_date"] = row.release_date;

                    //Add New Row to New Resulting Data Table
                    dtMovies.Rows.Add(drRow);
                }
                //return dtMyFriendsMovies;
            }
        } //FB FQL
```